# (Tensorflow) ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

I'm trying to combine a set of images into one np.array and convert it to a tf.data.Dataset object like so:

```
test = np.array([np.array(PIL.Image.open(image), dtype=np.float32) for image in image_list],
                dtype=object)

test_set = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(test)
```

But doing so raises the following error:

> ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?
Cheers

Comment: That's how a numpy array format is written. If you do `print(test)`, it will be printed in the format you want. There is nothing wrong with the output.

Answer (score 3):

Figured out the issue was caused by creating one np.array too many. Doing the following fixed it for me:

```
test = [np.array(PIL.Image.open(image), dtype=np.float32) for image in image_list]
```